# Returning by value to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm studying rvalue references and I have a doubt in the following code:

```
string func() {
    return "Paul";
}

int main()
{
    string&& nodanger = func();
    // The lifetime of the temporary is extended
    // to the life-time of the reference.
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: what does `func()` return?

I believe this is what happens:

- func returns a prvalue "Paul" (is this a const char * due to a rvalue->pointer conversion?)
- a string object is implicitly constructed (which ctor is used?)
- due to reference collapsing rules it is bound to "nodanger" (does this behave any differently from a string& normal reference?)

Comment: This won't even compile.  What is `middle_name()`?  Where are you returning an rvalue reference?  `func()` just returns a string by value so there is no rvalue reference with that.

Comment: Take a look at this article about [**Rvalue References and Move Semantics**](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html). As always **Alex Allain**, wrote a super article. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Your `func()` function returns an `std::string` prvalue. The [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) being used to construct the `std::string` is

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This prvalue is bound to the rvalue reference `nodanger`, which extends its lifetime to match that of the reference itself. Reference collapsing doesn't come into play here.

> does this behave any differently from a `string&` normal reference?

The code wouldn't compile if `nodanger` was a `string&` because you can't bind rvalues to non-`const` lvalue references. The lifetime extension behavior in your example is identical to the following case

```
std::string const& nodanger = func();
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely lots of confusion here. I'll assume `middle_name()` is supposed to be `func()`.

> The question is: what does func() return?

It returns a `string` (which I will assume is a `std::string`). This return object is initialised with the expression `"Paul"` which has type "array of 5 `const` `char`". The constructor used is the following:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

To call this function, the string literal has to undergo implicit array-to-pointer conversion (taking us from a `const char[5]` to a `const char*`.

The expression `func()` is a prvalue expression (a subset of rvalue expressions) because it returns by value. Here's how the standard defines this:

> A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

It doesn't make sense to say "returns a prvalue". A "prvalue" is not an object or a type. It's a category of expression. The expression which calls `func` is a prvalue.

The rvalue reference binds to the `std::string` object that has been returned from the function. There's no reference collapsing going on here. If the reference were an lvalue reference instead, your code wouldn't compile because a non-`const` lvalue reference can't bind to an rvalue expression.